# Sorting Czech in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, unicode, multilingual

I have the following perl program

```
use 5.014_001;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;


require 'Unicode/Collate/Locale/cs.pl';

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @old_list = (
        "cash",
        "Cash",
        "cat",
        "Cat",
        "čash",
        "dash",
        "Dash",
        "Ďash",
        "database",
        "Database",
        );


my $col= Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(
    level => 3,                    
    locale => 'cs',
    normalization => 'NFD',
);


my @list = $col->sort(@old_list);

foreach my $item (@list){

    print $item, "\n";

}
```

This program prints out the output:

cash
Cash
cat
Cat
čash
dash
Dash
Ďash
database
Database

I believe that a careful observer would have to conclude that in Czech either

1. **č** is a first-class letter while **Ď** is not.
2. The Unicode::Collate::Locale sorting of Czech in Perl is not correct

I'd like to believe (1), and the following bolsters my case:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index_talk:Czech

where it says:

Let us sort the entries by the existing Czech conventions, as far as practicable. That is, only the following characters have any sorting significance:

a b c č d e f g h ch i j k l m n o p q r ř s š t u v w x y z ž

But I'm confused, because I thought "D with a v over it" (and it's lowercase equivalent), is a first-class letter of the Czech alphabet.

Where is @tchrist when I need him?

I'd appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Czech, but if CLDR does not specify that in Czech, *ď* is its own letter collating after *d* the way that *č* is its own letter collating after *c*, then that would explain what you are seeing. It is possible to introduce tailoring in the collator if you need it to behave differently than it does with the default of `--locale => "cs"` by using a carefully crafted  `--entry` argument to the constructor with overriding DUCET elements specified precisely. I didn’t get your ping because you didn’t comment on a post of mine or add a comment to one of my comment chains.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet seen a language that would correctly order Czech or Slovak words. (Slovak is quite similar to Czech alphabet.) .NET, Java, Python, all get it wrong. The closest to the correct solution are Raku and Go.

Yes, in Czech and Slovak, ď letter comes (right) after d. There are quite a few peculiarities, such as digraphs ch, dz, dž.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.30;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;

use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";

my @words = qw/čaj auto pot márny kľak chyba drevo cibuľa džíp džem šum pól čučoriedka 
    banán čerešňa červený klam čierny tŕň pôst hôrny mat chobot cesnak kĺb mäta ďateľ 
    troska sýkorka elektrón fuj zem guma hora gejzír ihla pýr hrozno jazva džavot lom/;

my $col = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(
    level => 3,                    
    locale => 'sk',
    normalization => 'NFKC',
);

my @sort_asc = $col->sort(@words);
say "@sort_asc";
```

The example sorts Slovak words; it contains plenty of challenges.

```
$./sort_accented_words.pl 
auto banán cesnak cibuľa čaj čerešňa červený čierny čučoriedka ďateľ drevo 
džavot džem džíp elektrón fuj gejzír guma hora hôrny hrozno chobot chyba 
ihla jazva kľak klam kĺb lom márny mat mäta pól pot pôst pýr sýkorka šum 
tŕň troska zem
```

Perl did not order the accented words correctly. Interestingly, it correctly ordered the words with ch, dz, dž digraphs.

```
#!/usr/bin/raku

my @words = <čaj auto pot márny kľak chyba drevo cibuľa džíp džem šum pól čučoriedka 
    banán čerešňa červený klam čierny tŕň pôst hôrny mat chobot cesnak kĺb mäta ďateľ 
    troska sýkorka elektrón fuj zem guma hora gejzír ihla pýr hrozno jazva džavot lom>;

say @words.sort({ .unival, .NFKD[0], .fc });
```

This is a Raku example.

```
./sort_words.raku 
(auto banán cesnak chobot chyba cibuľa čaj čerešňa červený čierny čučoriedka
 drevo džavot džem džíp ďateľ elektrón fuj gejzír guma hora hrozno hôrny ihla
 jazva klam kĺb kľak lom mat márny mäta pot pól pôst pýr sýkorka šum troska 
tŕň zem)
```

Accented words are correctly sorted but the ch, dz, and dž digraphs are wrong.

So in my opinion, unless we create our own solution, we won't get a 100% correct output in any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

A locale is just a set of rules. Here's the [locale for `cs` from Collate::Locale 1.31](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/SADAHIRO/Unicode-Collate-1.31/Collate/Locale/cs.pl). [DUCET](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) is the Default Unicode Collation Element Table.

The Ď may be a first class letter, but that's not what DUCET thinks. If you want different sorts, you can adjust your locale or supply your own.

```
+{
   locale_version => 1.31,
   entry => <<'ENTRY', # for DUCET v13.0.0
010D      ; [.1FD7.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON
0063 030C ; [.1FD7.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON
010C      ; [.1FD7.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CARON
0043 030C ; [.1FD7.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CARON
0063 0068 ; [.2076.0020.0002] # <LATIN SMALL LETTER C, LATIN SMALL LETTER H>
0063 0048 ; [.2076.0020.0007][.0000.0000.0002] # <LATIN SMALL LETTER C, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H>
0043 0068 ; [.2076.0020.0007][.0000.0000.0008] # <LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C, LATIN SMALL LETTER H>
0043 0048 ; [.2076.0020.0008] # <LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H>
0159      ; [.2194.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON
0072 030C ; [.2194.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON
0158      ; [.2194.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH CARON
0052 030C ; [.2194.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH CARON
0161      ; [.21D3.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
0073 030C ; [.21D3.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
0160      ; [.21D3.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
0053 030C ; [.21D3.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
017E      ; [.2287.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
007A 030C ; [.2287.0020.0002] # LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
017D      ; [.2287.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
005A 030C ; [.2287.0020.0008] # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
ENTRY
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If the default sort is not working for you, this common workaround is an easy do-it-yourself:

Make a sort-array by transforming your strings: if `a` and `á` should be equivalent, transform both to `a`; if `á` should follow `a`, transform it into `a[`, for example (any character after `z` should be fine). Transform `ch` into `h[`, as it goes after `h`, if I understand correctly.  Then sort the original array together with the sort-array.

Comment: I'm hoping that either (1) someone verifies that my results are correct (2) There's someway of "fixing" this using something like tailoring, which I really don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

Despite Czech being my native language, I don't know Czech collation perfectly. But surely, for ď, ť, ň and wovels with diacritics, the diacritics has a lower signifficance than for other Czech characters like č.

Why? This is related to pronunciation. Barring assimilation and non-native words, all consonants but d, t and n have clear pronunciation regardless of their context. (“Ch” is considered as a separate letter.) Those three letters (D, T and N) can be “softened” when they are followed by “i”, “í” or “ě”. In those cases, they are prononuced like they had a caron (háček). As a result, the diacritics for them is less signifficant.